# query to merge records based on value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to merge the value records as single row based on ID value.I want to display table1 value along with table2 value as single row. I want to display all in single record for the id=15.In table 1 ID is sub_id in table 2. 
I want output as
Id content_value value as(15,cake,chocolate,enila,strabery)

[image]

```
select a.*,b.CONTENT_VALUE as multitype from album as a,album_details as b where a.ID=b.SUB_ID
```

Comment: 'venila' I can forgive, but 'strabery'?

Comment: @Strawberry: OP seems doesn't know you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to get as different columns for each value or content_value since the number of rows is dynamic.You can get the values like this by joining two tables. ie as two columns (ID and all content_value & value).

```
SELECT t1.ID, CONCAT_WS(',', t1.content_value, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.value)) AS contents FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.sub_id = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID;
```

Comment: Given that a presentation layer is available (php), this seems like a poor solution to me.